# Calculate average about the return of an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

The given oberservable has the following structure

```
... interface experimentalresult {
   Name: User;
   Results: {
     Experiment: Task
     Attempts: Number
     Status: Boolean
   } [];
```

I would like to calculate the average attempts of all users who have passed the experiment with a positive status (true). This average should then be given to an array based on the experiments (task).
It should then be something that the array looks like this.

> ['2.7', '3.4', 2.1 ']

Semantically, the results should be the following facts:

> ['average experiment for experiment 1', 'average experimental
> experiment 2', ....]

Can this complicated fact be implemented with a simply subscribe? If this is not the case, someone has a different suggestion as you can implement this function.

Comment: You have Status in your interface twice which makes your question harder to understand - Maybe you can provide a small subset of data

Comment: The first Status has no relevance for the problem. I edited the code and hope its more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The shell of what you want looks like this:

```
this.myObservable$.pipe(
  map((expResults: experimentalresult[]) => {
    return getAverages(expResults)
  })
).subscribe((nicelyFormattedArrayResult: any) => {
  console.log(nicelyFormattedArrayResult)
})
```

And your getAverages function looks like this. Note that you did not, in your code, show what `Experiment: Task` looks like so I've just treated it as a string. Of course, you will need to convert this to call `this.getAverages` etc, but that's really simple for you to do and I wanted to insert a working code snippet here.

```js
const expResults = [{
  Name: 'Barbara',
  Results: [
    {
      Experiment: 'experiment 1',
      Attempts: 5,
      Status: false // for calculation purposes this is ignored because Status is false
    },
    {
      Experiment: 'experiment 2',
      Attempts: 7,
      Status: true
    }   
  ]
},
{
  Name: 'Bob',
  Results: [
    {
      Experiment: 'experiment 1',
      Attempts: 3,
      Status: true
    },
    {
      Experiment: 'experiment 2',
      Attempts: 4,
      Status: true
    }   
  ]
}]

const getAverages = (expResults) => {

  const resultsObj = expResults.reduce((acc, expResult) => {
    expResult.Results.forEach(exp => {
      if (exp.Status) {
        if (acc[exp.Experiment] == null) acc[exp.Experiment] = []
        acc[exp.Experiment].push(exp.Attempts)
      }
    })
    return acc;
  }, {})

  const finalResult = Object.keys(resultsObj).map(key => {
    const count = resultsObj[key].length
    const sum = resultsObj[key].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    return {key, average: sum / count}
  })
  
  return finalResult;
}

const answer = getAverages(expResults)

console.log('answer', answer)
```

Comment: @Jonas960 Is the data coming off the observable ... experimentalresult ... OR ... experimentalresult[] (viz an array of experimentalresult)?

Comment: it is experimentalresult[]

Comment: updated answer to give full working solution based on experimentalresult[]

Comment: Thank you for your help, it helped me alot. I have one last question. Is there a way to do that without the "reduce"? My intellij says "reduce does not exists on Type Observable".

Comment: I can only guess you are getting an error on this line ... expResults.reduce ... the only reason you would get the error you are talking about is if expResults was an Observable ... however, expResults should be an experimentalresult[] array ... make sure you are passing the correct thing into the getAverages function

Comment: Alternatively, if the codes working and intellij is just wrongly detecting an issue, just put the problem on ignore